# Put application wide functions in ajaxStop method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new in ajax base application development

When developing a non ajax web application we use our common codes in $(document).ready

```
$( document ).ready(function(  ) {
//Here we do common tasks like mask inputs, enable all inputs, show tooltips if any:
 $(".mask-date").mask("00/00/00");
 $('input').attr('disabled', false);
 $('[data-tooltip!=""]').qtip();
});
```

Now we are developing a fully ajax base application, WHERE ALL PAGES ARE LOADED VIA AJAX (user clicks on menu and the new content is loaded in a div via jquery ajax call. This new conent could be forms, simple text, charts ... ). In this case the *$( document ).ready* is not working any more. As it is not triggered when new page content is loaded with ajax.

Now I put all the common functions in ajaxStop as below:

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function(  ) {
//Here we do common tasks like mask inputs or enable all inputs:
 $(".mask-date").mask("00/00/00");
 $('input').attr('disabled', false);
 $('[data-tooltip!=""]').qtip();

});
```

It works but is it correct approach ?!

Comment: I mean, it works, and will continue to work, but whether or not it is the correct approach is too opinionated. I never use the ajaxStart/Stop methods for anything other than showing a loading graphic, anything else i tend to instead use the success and error callbacks.

Comment: @KevinB then where do you suggest these common methods?

Comment: *"anything else i tend to instead use the success and error callbacks."*